# Iterate through Json Object with nested Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to iterate this json and push the values into an other array

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Samson",
    "marcaModelo": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "nombre": "API 6D "
        }
    ]
}
{
    "id": 6,
    "nombre": "Endress + Hauser",
    "marcaModelo": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "nombre": "Proline t-mass 65F50-AK2AH1RCBBCA"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "nombre": "Cerabar M"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I made out with this

```
Object.entries(res).forEach((value, key) => {
      console.log(key, value)
      this.marcas.push({
        'marcaId': res[key].id,
        'marcaNombre': res[key].nombre,
        'modeloId': res[key].marcaModelo[0].id,
        'modeloNombre': res[key].marcaModelo[0].nombre
      })
      console.log(this.marcas)
    })
```

but only push one marcaModelo object into marcas array, if I replace marcaModelo[0] for marcaModelo[key] I get an undefined.

I need something like this

```
{
marcaId:6
marcaNombre:"Endress + Hauser"
modeloId:[10, 8]
modeloNombre:[Proline t-mass 65F50-AK2AH1RCBBCA, Cerabar M]
}
```

Comment: I think you need to be more specific. What do you want the result to look like.

Comment: Hard to guess what your expected results are if you don't show us

Comment: You don't need to use `res[key]`, just use `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a nested loop for all the `marcaModelo` objects; you can use `.map()` to return an array of the results of a function on each element.. It also doesn't seem like you need to use `Object.entries()`. The original object is an array, you can use `.forEach()` directly on it.

```
res.forEach(value => {
    console.log(value);
    this.marcas.push({
        'marcaId': value.id,
        'marcaNombre': value.nombre,
        'modeloId': value.marcaModelo.map(o => o.id),
        'modeloNombre': value.marcaModelo.map(o => o.nombre)
    });
    console.log(this.marcas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
res.map(({ id, nombre, marcaModelo }) => ({
    marcaId: id,
    marcaNombre: nombre,
    modeloId: marcaModelo.map(m => m.id),
    modeloNombre: marcaModelo.map(m => m.nombre),
}));
```